# Can I programmatically add layout in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my fragment I have a `LinearLayout`, which I want to populate with `TextViews`and `Buttons`

In my `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkout, container, false);
    container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    return v;
}
```

Why is my container grayed out?

I'm trying this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
       TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
       text.setText(x);
       container.addView(text);
}
```

But it just exits. Can I do this in `fragments`?

Answer (score 1):

- You should add `TextView` you defined in your code .Just like `text`.
  `tvOrder` may be existed in your layout .
- And your `onCreteView` method should return `View` .

You can do this .

**Edit**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--you should add item here-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_sub_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--you should not add item here, and you can programatically add layout in it ?-->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your code

```
private LinearLayout container,mySubLinearLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkout, container, false);
    container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    // add here 
    mySubLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.my_sub_linear);
    return v;
}
```

And this code

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    text.setText(x + "");
    mySubLinearLayout.addView(text);
}
```

**Note**

If you want to programatically add layout , you should set a empty layout .

Also you can remove the all view in your code .

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the following code, because you are setting integer value on your text view.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
       TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
       text.setText(String.valueOf(x));
       container.addView(text);
}
```